# Where can I find words that have "literary meaning" like "ardent", "antic"

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, literary-english

Is there a place on the Interent where we can find words with meaning that marked as *literary* in the Oxford Dictionaries (Lexico) like these:

> [for](https://books.google.it/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA682&lpg=PA682&dq=%22he%20felt%20guilty,%20for%20he%20knew%20that%20he%20bore%20a%20share%20of%20responsibility%20for%20Fanny%27s%20death%22&source=bl&ots=T_iwdtoGxL&sig=ACfU3U38DAXKo5qelcmsZC-2S2wGqK0j0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR68DFk8TjAhXQ_KQKHZr0BQIQ6AEwBXoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22he%20felt%20guilty%2C%20for%20he%20knew%20that%20he%20bore%20a%20share%20of%20responsibility%20for%20Fanny's%20death%22&f=false)
>
> *literary*: because; since: he felt guilty, for he knew that he bore a
>   share of responsibility for Fanny's death.

> [antic](http://www.memidex.com/antic+strange)
>
> *literary*: grotesque or bizarre.

> [pinion](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pinion)
>
> *literary*: a bird's wing as used in flight.

> [ardent](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ardent)
>
> *archaic* or *literary*: burning; glowing

I tried googling it but only found list of terms like "oxymoron" that describe different figure of speech..

Comment: Get a [Latin dictionary](http://www.babylon.com/define/112/Latin-Dictionary.html). Any word you find in both a Latin and an English dictionary has "literary meaning" in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler The word Latin I found in a Latin dictionary doesn't have "literary meaning".

Comment: You picked the wrong word. Try again. Apparently you are the only one who knows what "literary meaning" is, so you'll have to do all the finding yourself, looks like.

Comment: The Latin connection could be incidental (even if essential) but a stylistic class should have been listed out in its entirety sometime somewhere by someone.

Comment: Could be listed on meta and/or linguisticsSE so those who know of a resource could help.

Comment: One straight off possibility is to ask OED for such a list -- that will be an authentic list to boot.

Comment: @Kris Yes. True!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you think this would better fit the meta with "resources" tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how much time/energy/money/programming you are willing to throw at this problem, the Oxford English Dictionary provides [an API](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/oxford-english-dictionary/) for querying the dictionary; you could just ask for words with definitions with the "literary" tag.

Comment: Cool! Never heard about that before.

Comment: +1 Great idea indeed. Any idea what that 'category' (field-name) is called (by OED at least)? Usage?

Comment: @Kris I'm no longer convinced that this is a possible solution; the search API is very limited and not exceptionally well-documented, and if you have access to the OED online you can just use their advanced search from the website to achieve essentially the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Try the following lists.
Number 1 meets your specifications, although it is by no means comprehensive, while the rest are lists of archaic words, which my New American Oxford Dictionary sometimes labels as *literary* as well. Number 5 is the most comprehensive of the lists.

1. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/literary-words
2. http://phrontistery.info/archaic.html
3. https://www.vocabulary.com/lists/13150
4. https://www.vocabulary.com/lists/18058
5. http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/words.html